# How to insert test-time environment variable with pytest pyproject.toml

Tags: pytest, pyproject.toml

Usually, when defining a Environment Variable for `pytest` using the `pytest-env` plugin, this is done using `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
env =
    DATA_DIR = data/test_assets
```

`pytest` supports `pyproject.toml` since 6.0. How is an Environment Variable supposed be defined in this format? The following does not work:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
env = [
    {DATA_DIR = "data/test_assets"}
]
```

Answer (score 17):

The correct format is:

```
env = [
    "DATA_DIR = data/test_assets",
    "ROSETTA = rosetta/main"
]
```

Comment: that is correct, as I mentioned in my answer, you need to remove the curly braces as they do not mesh with the plug-in

Answer (score 4):

So the issue resides with the `pytest-env` plugin. First of all, it seems to have been abandoned by its maintainers as it has not been updated since 2017. It comes down to how the plugin parses the part of the `toml` file as shown [here](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env/blob/master/pytest_env/plugin.py#L25-#L28).

The issue is specifically this [line](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env/blob/master/pytest_env/plugin.py#L26). When parsing the contents of your `pyproject.toml` it transforms what you have in to the following:

```
part = e.partition("=")
# ('{DATA_DIR ', '=', ' "data/test_assets"}')
key = part[0].strip()
# '{DATA_DIR'
```

That means it transforms your environment variable to have the key of `'{DATA_DIR'` hence why it does not seem to be working as expected. You need to either switch back to the previous format you were using for environment variables or remove the curly brackets as they seem to not mesh with this plugin.